# How can I cancel an Android Device Manager Erase command?

Tags: android-device-manager

Using Android Device Manager from my PC, several devices are listed, including one that no longer belongs to me. While attempting to remove this device from my list I inadvertently sent an 'Erase' command to the other devices. Fortunately, none of these devices had Android Device Manager enabled as a device manager, so the request was ignored. Phew! But I'm now a bit concerned that the request will be pending, and that at some time in the future an Android software upgrade will enable Device Manager and my data will disappear.

Can anyone tell me a way of cancelling the 'Erase' command, or whether the command will 'time-out' at some time?

Answer (score 1):

ADM only works if the device is signed into the Google account that you're using in the web interface. If the device in question no longer belongs to you, presumably it will never sign into your account, so there's nothing to worry about.

Comment: Thanks, Dan. That's reassuring. Also, I just checked a bit more carefully and what I thought was an attempt to erase the data on all my devices was just a Gmail sent to all my devices telling me that ADM was about to erase the data on the device that no longer belongs to me. Breathing a hearty sigh of relief...

Comment: This answer doesn't work for the scenario where you send a wipe signal to your phone, but then recover your phone and want to avoid wiping it but continue using it.